# Hyper-V NAT Network Inaccessible When Going from Wired to Wireless

Tags: hyper-v, nat

I've got a NAT network setup on my laptop.

```
## Create NAT Network
New-VMSwitch -SwitchName "barney" -SwitchType Internal
New-NetIPAddress -IPAddress 10.10.0.1 -PrefixLength 24 -InterfaceIndex 33
New-NetNat -Name 'barney-nat' -InternalIPInterfaceAddressPrefix '10.10.0.0/24'
```

When I'm wired up in the office, I'm good as gold. I've got a bunch of Hyper-V machines. They can connect to one another, my host, and the internet. When I go on wifi, still good. When I VPN into the office, my Hyper-V network dies miserably. Networking is not my thing. Any quick hits I can check?

Answer (score 0):

The issue had nothing to do with the active NIC on my laptop. When I VPN'ed into the office, my Hyper-v network died. Not sure why.